# Parametric equations of an elliptical curve resulting from the intersection of a cone and a plane

Tags: conic-sections

[Cone-plane intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJjmN.jpg). I feel like the math is beyond me  for this one. Anyways, I have a right circular cone with its apex on the x-y plane. I know all the dimensions of the cone including the orientation of the cone axis.

I translate the cone such that its apex now lies below the plane. The plane cuts the cone producing an elliptical curve.

I know there are other conic sections possible but I'm more interested in the elliptical case. Is it possible to find the equation of the elliptical curve?

Edit: I'm trying to find the parametric equations for the cone in the second pic. If anyone could help me with that, I think I can figure out the rest.
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKtyO.jpg)

Comment: Send the the cone and the plane equations

Comment: Can you come up with an equation that describes the cone? Once you have that, simply set $z=0$ in it.

Comment: Please see my updated post

Comment: Conic sections are formed when $ \cos  \gamma / \cos\alpha =e $ where $ \alpha $ is semi-vertical angle and $\gamma $ is inclination of cutting plane to symmetry axis.For ellipse former angle is smaller.